# Como usar a função ggTS com ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Olá, alguém sabe, tem usado a função ggTS para fazer gráficos Temperatura/Salinidade com ggplot?
Não estou sabendo como instalar para fazer que funcione junto com ggplot.

https://github.com/Davidatlarge/ggTS

Obrigado,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para instalar é só clonar o repositório ou descarregar o ficheiro .zip. `ggTS` não é um pacote é uma *função* R, que depende dos seguintes pacotes CRAN:

```
pacotes <- c('gsw', 'dplyr', 'purrr', 'tidyr', 'isoband')
install.packages(pacotes)
```

Depois, para correr o primeiro exemplo do link da pergunta:

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd('~/R/ggTS-master')
example <- read.csv('example_data/example_data.csv')
setwd(old_dir)

ggTS(sal = example$salinity, 
     pot.temp = example$potential.temperature, 
     reference.p = 0,
     col.par = example$depth, 
     col.name = "depth [m]")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado @Rui Barradas.